# Wifi adapter is not detected by Ubuntu 18

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, adapter

I have a strange problem with my wifi adapter. It is not detected if I directly login to Ubuntu 18. But, in windows 10 it is readily detected. But after loging into windows, if I restart my PC and login to Ubuntu, ubuntu is able to detect it and I can access internet using the adapter.

To the best of my knowledge the required driver is mt7601 from MediaTek. Kindly suggest what I can do to fix this problem.

Comment: This is the 'classic' behavior for an unsupported chipset.  I'm guessing that this is a usb adapter.  You might want to try `lsusb` to get the product id for the adapter and makes sure that the driver supports the chipset (e.g. start with a websearch on the usb id).  You might need to download a new driver . . . mediatek has better support in recent kernels but not perfect.

Comment: In PCI case please add output of `lspci -vv | grep -E -i "Network|Wireless|Centrino|Mediatek" -A7` to the question.